# Spooler SubSystem App takes high cpu?

Tags: cpu, print-spooler

I'm using windows 10 and updated automatically about two days ago.

I just realized that "Spooler SubSystem App" takes about 30% of my CPU time.

Restart does not work. (it's just there after reboot)

I don't have any printers.

Tried to close the spooler service but it's already closed.

Can not kill the process.

The process name is 'spoolsv.exe'

Memory usage is not high.

Googled it but couldn't find any solution.

Doe anybody know about this? please help. My CPU is burning for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Create a .bat file and run as administrator with the following lines

net stop spooler
del /Q /F /S "%systemroot%\System32\Spool\Printers*.*"
net start spooler

Comment: More info: https://www.howtogeek.com/323332/what-is-spooler-subsystem-app-spoolsv.exe-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-pc/

Comment: I did this and it did not help: once I restart the spooler, it still takes about 30% of my CPU.